# How to invoke a function of vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

For my understanding, The Vue component is a class,
So I can include it like:

```
import MyDialogComponent from './MyDialog.vue'
```

create an instance:

```
<my-dialog-component/>
```

Looks like I could assign the `visibility` property like:

```
prop: ['showDialog'] //delcare property
...
<md-dialog :md-active.sync="getActive"> 
...
computed:{ getActive: function () { return this.showDialog } } 
...
<my-dialog-component show-dialog='true'/>
```

To make dialog component visible. when I try to show dialog by button clicking.
Everything becomes complicate. Many variables need to declare and bind on both sides. But actually only one property I am using, the visibility of `MyDialog`.

So to show `MyDialog`, anyway like this?

```
myDialog1.showMe()
```

Invoke the public function of the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `ref` to your component

eg: `<my-dialog-component ref="dialog1" />`

then in you code:

```
this.$refs.dialog1.showMe()
```